# I can not to run feature.file from Rubymine

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, rubymine, feature-file

Can someone tell me where is my mistake?.
I'm trying to run the feature from Run but I haven't had success.
If I run via terminal it is possible. I've tried several ways but still succeeding.

[image]

```
 :\Ruby27-x64\bin\ruby.exe -EUTF-8 -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:\Ruby27-x64\bin/cucumber C:/Users/stadeuauli/RubymineProjects/Automation/features/specs/login.feature --format Teamcity::Cucumber::Formatter --expand --tags @loga_user --color -r features
    Testing started at 19:08 ...
    cannot load such file -- cucumber/core/ast/empty_multiline_argument
    Error creating formatter: Teamcity::Cucumber::Formatter (LoadError)
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
    C:/Program Files/JetBrains/RubyMine 2017.1.2/rb/testing/patch/bdd/teamcity/cucumber/common.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
    C:/Program Files/JetBrains/RubyMine 2017.1.2/rb/testing/patch/bdd/teamcity/cucumber/formatter_03103.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
    C:/Program Files/JetBrains/RubyMine 2017.1.2/rb/testing/patch/bdd/teamcity/cucumber/formatter.rb:72:in `<module:Cucumber>'
    C:/Program Files/JetBrains/RubyMine 2017.1.2/rb/testing/patch/bdd/teamcity/cucumber/formatter.rb:38:in `<module:Teamcity>'
    C:/Program Files/JetBrains/RubyMine 2017.1.2/rb/testing/patch/bdd/teamcity/cucumber/formatter.rb:37:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/constantize.rb:19:in `rescue in constantize'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/constantize.rb:8:in `constantize'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/configuration.rb:221:in `formatter_class'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/configuration.rb:208:in `block in formatter_factories'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/configuration.rb:207:in `map'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/configuration.rb:207:in `formatter_factories'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:212:in `formatters'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:192:in `report'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:80:in `run!'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:29:in `execute!'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cucumber-7.1.0/bin/cucumber:9:in `<top (required)>'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
    C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/cucumber:23:in `<top (required)>'
    -e:1:in `load'
    -e:1:in `<main>'
    
    Process finished with exit code 2
```

Comment: Just to be sure, have you tried RubyMine 2021.3? Does the problem persist there?

Comment: @Olivia 
True, I'm going to test this version that you indicated, it may be that the problem is with the version itself. Thank'u Olivia